# To check if a software/application is installed in Linux

Tags: tomcat, rhel

I am working on RHEL 6 and would like to check if Tomcat is installed in the system. The Tomcat process is not running. Basically looking for some Unix utility which can detect the third party software installed in the system.

Answer (score 2):

Try

`rpm -qa | grep tomcat`

the `rpm -qa` will list all packages, the `grep` filters for the string "tomcat"

This will not require root access.

**EDIT2**

In case your application is installed from source,  I think you can try as follows

`which tomcat`

that might come up with "/usr/sbin/tomcat" or something similar.

else try

`find /usr/ -name 'tomcat' 2> /dev/null`

replace the `/usr/` portion with another path where you suspect it can be present. else, try with just `/` .

or even

`locate tomcat | less`

to have a look all paths related to tomcat.

In case you have the source directory from which it was installed, you can get the paths from there from the makefile.

Comment: Installation not done via rpm package but by compiling the source code available online.

Comment: Tomcat isn't installed in default path... In one of the servers it is in /opt but this too varies from server to server. I have been using :

Comment: @RohitKandiyal I think if you just bruteforce it with `find` you will eventually find it, if it is present in the system.

Comment: Thanks Phoxis...
But the issue is Tomcat isn't installed in default path... In one of the servers it is in /opt but this too varies from server to server. I have been using :
find / -name "catalina"

But this become very time consuming and was looking for some alternative.

Comment: @RohitKandiyal Your options are to either look in a few known locations for a know file name - which will be rather fast,  or to search your entire file system for a particular file, which could be rather slow. When people can download arbitrary files (like Tomcat) and place them wherever they want on a machine, there are no alternatives.

Comment: `locate` will be fast, and it will only if the database is updated. See `updatedb` .

Answer (score 0):

`$ find / -name "*tomcat*"`

That should get you at least something relevant if it's present. It's going to take a while to run, though...